# Click different links on the page selenium / java

Tags: java, html, selenium

Main Page :https://YYYYYYY.YYY/ssi/?env=Production

I have 5 different URLs in a table format in my main page. I want to click on each of these links one by one and validate if the page opened and displayed the text "SSI".

Example : If i click the link to "ssi-1-a" in the mainpage, I want to validate the text "SSI" in the page that loads after clicking. After Validating, I need to return back to my main page without using Back Button and I need to click on "ssi-2-a" and so on.

```
<document>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<b>Status as of </b>
Wed Oct 25 16:57:57 2017
<br/>
<br/>
This page shows the current version and build date of the SSI code loaded     into the JVMs that constitute the environment you selected.
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div style="float:left">
    <table style="display:inline-table" width="500" border="1">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
          <tr>
          <tr>
          <th>Prod</th>
            <td style="background-color:rgb(96,192,96)" align="center">
              <a href="https://XXXXXXX010.XXX-XX.net:12345/ssiadmin/">ssi-1-a</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <th>Prod</th>
           <td style="background-color:rgb(96,192,96)" align="center">
            <a href="https://XXXXXXX020.XXX-XX.net:12345/ssiadmin/">ssi-2-a</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <th>Prod</th>
           <td style="background-color:rgb(96,192,96)" align="center">
            <a href="https://XXXXXXX030.XXX-XX.net:12345/ssiadmin/">ssi-3-a</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <th>Prod</th>
           <td style="background-color:rgb(96,192,96)" align="center">
            <a href="https://XXXXXXX040.XXX-XX.net:12345/ssiadmin/">ssi-4-a</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <th>Prod</th>
           <td style="background-color:rgb(96,192,96)" align="center">
            <a href="https://XXXXXXX050.XXX-XX.net:12345/ssiadmin/">ssi-5-a</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
</document>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi in order to click on multiple pages you need to create a list of urls.
And loop through every url and check for the element if it is found or not.

```
    List<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>();
    urlList.add("Add 5 urls here");
        for (String url : urlList) 
            {
                driver.get(url);
                try {
                    Element ssl = driver.findElementByXpath("/head/b/something");
                    if (ssl.isDisplayed()) {
                        // do something
                    }
                } catch (NoSuchElementException | TimeoutException e) {
                    // Not Found
                }
            }
```

Comment: @johnsonambrose you may accept the answer if this satisfied your query .